# Reference a figure and get latex to write the word "Figure" for you

Tags: cross-referencing

This might seem a bit lazy, but having come from a MS word world, my instinct is not to write the word "figure" every time I reference one in latex. This leads to me leaving the word figure out of some of my references, like this:

```
I reference \ref{fig:donkeykong}
```

and latex will output:

```
I reference 1.
```

When I would like it to output

```
I reference Figure 1
```

is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't `cleveref` just what you're asking for? There are plenty of posts about it here, and its documentation is well-written...

Comment: Welcome to TeXSX! The `cleveref` package  is done for that, if I understand correctly what  you want.

Comment: Thats exactly it guys thanks!!